# After meteor bundle, node.js is "LISTENING" but not showing up at localhost

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, mlab

I'm bundling a meteor app and running the uncompressed tarball with node.  I am not sure why the app doesn't seem to appear on localhost.  Here is how I'm bundling:

```
$ meteor bundle app.tar.gz
```

Then I uncompress:

```
$ tar -zxvf app.tar.gz
```

Then I cd into the bundle directory and do as the README says:

```
$ rm -r programs/server/node_modules/fibers
$ npm install fibers@1.0.1
$ export MONGO_URL='mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@<PORT>.mongolab.com:<PORT>/<db>'
$ export ROOT_URL='http://localhost:3000'
$ node main.js
```

Then, node says it is `LISTENING` but localhost:3000 doesn't connect.

I have node v0.10.22, and Meteor says bundle has only been tested with node v0.10.21, but it seems unlikely to be the problem.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to specify a `PORT`

```
export MONGO_URL='mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@<PORT>.mongolab.com:<PORT>/<db>'
export ROOT_URL='http://localhost:3000'
export PORT=3000
node main.js
```