# Meteor bundle just "LISTENING", application not reachable on localhost:3000

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584916/after-meteor-bundle-node-js-is-listening-but-not-showing-up-at-localhost). The question is the same; however, it is not a duplicate, since it did not solve my problem. By the way, is it correct to open a new question then?

```
$ meteor bundle app.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf app.tar.gz
```

This is what the `README` says:

```
$ rm -r programs/server/node_modules/fibers
$ npm install fibers@1.0.1
$ export MONGO_URL='mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@<PORT>.mongolab.com:<PORT>/<db>'
$ export ROOT_URL='http://localhost:3000'
$ node main.js
```

It says `LISTENING` but does not connect. The solution stated in the post I am referring to did not work for me. I wrote a script that does this:

```
export MONGO_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/$db_name'
export ROOT_URL=$root_url
export PORT=3000
```

The variables are set correctly. It's just `LISTENING` though.

When I run the following script, I get an error:

```
db_name="mydb"
root_url="http://my.domain.com"

echo $db_name
echo $root_url

export MONGO_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/$db_name'
export ROOT_URL='$root_url'
export PORT=3000

node bundle/main.js
```

This error:

```
/var/mypath/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:186
}).run();
   ^
Error: a route URL prefix must begin with a slash
    at _.extend.declare (packages/routepolicy/routepolicy.js:95)
    at new StreamServer (packages/livedata/stream_server.js:14)
    at new Server (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1012)
    at Package (packages/livedata/server_convenience.js:10)
    at packages/livedata.js:3980:4
    at packages/livedata.js:3991:3
    at /var/mypath/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach                     (/var/mypath/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /var/mypath/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
```

Comment: It works when I put all the `MONGO_URL` and `ROOT_URL` and `PORT` statement between `sudo <all these statements> node bundle/main.js`. It does not work with `export`, though. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the environment variables declared in my script are deleted after the script's execution. To prevent this behaviour, one can use `sudo -E ./myscript.sh`. The parameter `-E` preserves the environment. Now, my app is reachable. I found my solution [here](http://linux.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/linuxadmin-l/using-sudo-and-exporting-the-environment-variable-1765011).